La librería optree está realmente instalada, pero al ejecutar "from keras.models import Sequential" aún arroja ImportError ¿por qué?
Estoy intentando usar VS Code para iniciar un pequeño proyecto de ciencia de datos. Actualmente tengo problemas al importar keras al ejecutar las siguientes líneas:
# LSTM and GRU project
## Dependencies

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dropout, Dense

El TraceBack es el siguiente:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_21244\449270897.py in <cell line:
6>()
4 import matplotlib as mpl
5 from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
----> 6 from keras.models import Sequential
7 from keras.layers import LSTM, Dropout, Dense
c:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras_init_.py
in 
8
9 # Import everything from /api/ into keras.
---> 10 from keras.api import *  # noqa: F403
11 from keras.api import version  # Import * ignores names start with "_".
12
c:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\api_init_.py
in 
6
7
----> 8 from keras.api import activations
9 from keras.api import applications
10 from keras.api import backend
c:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\api\activations_init_.py
in 
5 """
6  ...
---> 10     raise ImportError(
11         "To use Keras, you need to have optree installed. "
12         "Install it via pip install optree"
ImportError: To use Keras, you need to have optree installed.
Install it via pip install optree Output is truncated. View as a
scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output
settings...

Decidí entonces ejecutar en la terminal comandos como pip install keras --upgrade --user para comprobar si alguna de las dependencias anteriores no estaba instalada, el resultado es bastante raro ya que indica que cada dependencia utilizada en este proyecto tiene sus requisitos satisfechos, a continuación comparto el registro:
C:\Users\ResetStoreX\Downloads\Cryptobote 2024> pip install numpy --upgrade --user
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (1.26.4)
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
C:\Users\ResetStoreX\Downloads\Cryptobote 2024> pip install optree --upgrade --user
Requirement already satisfied: optree in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.0.0 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from optree) (4.2.0)
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
C:\Users\ResetStoreX\Downloads\Cryptobote 2024> pip install keras --upgrade --user 
Requirement already satisfied: keras in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (3.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from keras) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: optree in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from keras) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from keras) (3.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ml-dtypes in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from keras) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from keras) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rich in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from keras) (13.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.0.0 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from optree->keras) (4.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments<3.0.0,>=2.14.0 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from rich->keras) (2.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mdurl~=0.1 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from markdown-it-py<3.0.0,>=2.1.0->rich->keras) (0.1.2)
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
C:\Users\ResetStoreX\Downloads\Cryptobote 2024> pip install pandas --upgrade --user 
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.7 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2024.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pandas) (2021.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.22.4 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->pandas) (1.16.0)
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
C:\Users\ResetStoreX\Downloads\Cryptobote 2024> pip install matplotlib --upgrade --user 
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (3.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from matplotlib) (24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-resources>=3.2.0 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (6.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (4.33.3)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.3.1 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=8 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (8.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: contourpy>=1.0.1 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.3.1 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=3.1.0 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from importlib-resources>=3.2.0->matplotlib) (3.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib) (1.16.0)
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

Mi intérprete de Python es Python 3.9.6 de 64 bits, y estoy seguro de que todas las dependencias anteriores se instalaron en su ruta correspondiente. Intenté desinstalar y reinstalar keras y optree, sin olvidar la ejecución de pip cache purge además de reiniciar el kernel, pero todavía me sigue arrojando el mismo error.
También noté que keras.models y keras.layers están subrayados, y cuando "paso el cursor sobre ellos" se muestra:

Import "keras.models" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)

Entonces, estoy estancado, me gustaría saber qué debo hacer para resolver esto.

Tengo el mismo problema. Con la versión de Python 3.11, instalé tanto la librería tensorflow como keras, pero no me permite importarlo (me lo subraya) from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam Al ejecutar mi código aparece este error: *I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appr

@Sara He decidido de momento usar un notebook de Deepnote, ya que para lo que necesito hacer todas estas librerías vienen preinstaladas y funcionales. Te recomiendo hacer lo mismo si sigues con el problema.

¡Lo resolví!
En mi caso al parecer el problema tenía que ver con la librería typing_extensions que estaba desactualizada, me di cuenta de la siguiente forma, ejecuté el siguiente comando en una celda de Jupyter Notebook:
import optree
import keras
print(optree.__version__)
print(keras.__version__)

El cual arrojó el siguiente Traceback:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_27656\3452976656.py in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import optree
      2 import keras
      3 print(optree.__version__)
      4 print(keras.__version__)

c:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\optree\__init__.py in <module>
     15 """OpTree: Optimized PyTree Utilities."""
     16 
---> 17 from optree import integration, typing
     18 from optree.ops import (
     19     MAX_RECURSION_DEPTH,

c:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\optree\typing.py in <module>
     36     Union,
     37 )
---> 38 from typing_extensions import NamedTuple  # Generic NamedTuple: Python 3.11+
     39 from typing_extensions import OrderedDict  # Generic OrderedDict: Python 3.7.2+
     40 from typing_extensions import Self  # Python 3.11+

ImportError: cannot import name 'NamedTuple' from 'typing_extensions' (c:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py)

Buscando por el stackoverflow en ingles encontré esta respuesta a un problema semejante, así mismo, ejecuté dicho comando (pip install typing_extensions==4.7.1 --upgrade) en la terminal cmd de VS Code, después de eso tuve que ejecutar pip install tensorflow, luego ejecutar pip install numpy==1.23.5, y finalmente reiniciar el kernel de Python para poder hacer uso de las dependencias sin problema y sin advertencias ni errores .

Interpretando los logs de salida del pip, parece que está instalado.
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from keras) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: optree in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from keras) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from keras) (3.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ml-dtypes in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from keras) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from keras) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rich in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from keras) (13.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.0.0 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from optree->keras) (4.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments<3.0.0,>=2.14.0 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from rich->keras) (2.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mdurl~=0.1 in c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from markdown-it-py<3.0.0,>=2.1.0->rich->keras) (0.1.2)
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

El aviso:
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

Puede ser algunos avisos pero nada grave.Debe dar atención a algunos detalles.
actualize o pip e o setuptools
pip install --upgrade pip

.
pip install --upgrade setuptools

Otra forma de instalar, setup.py
Al extraer todos los archivos entre en el directorio por el prompt de comando e instale
python setup.py install

Atentese a las especificaciones del Kera:
Para utilizar el Keras 3, también tendrá que instalar un framework de backend – JAX, TensorFlow o PyTorch:

¿Qué versiones de Python están instaladas? Existe la posibilidad de
que el sistema tenga dos versiones de Python para diferentes
propósitos. Puede haber Python 3.10 y otra Python 3.9, y el sistema
esté utilizando como predeterminada Python 3.9, pero lo que se está
utilizando es Python 3.10. Cuando se intenta instalar un nuevo
paquete, la instalación puede estar en la versión 3.9 y no en la 3.10.

Si hay otras versiones, el sistema considerará la versión estándar y no la versión que desea utilizar.
Para asegurarse de que está utilizando la versión correcta, cree un script simple y ejecútelo. Si no es la versión 3.9, que es la versión que contiene las instalaciones exitosas, deberá cambiar al intérprete 3.9.
import sys
print("versão atual {sys.version[:8]}")

Por los registros, indica que los paquetes fueron instalados en esta versión del intérprete: c:\users\resetstorex\appdata\local\programs\python\python39
Lo que puede ayudar también es usar un entorno virtual, creando un espacio de trabajo solo para el proyecto para la versión específica de Python que estás utilizando.

Sí bien pude resolver mi duda, voy a darte los puntos que puse como recompensa por el esfuerzo que pusiste en redactar tu respuesta, saludos!
